# When is the PPF convex to the origin?

Tags: production-function

Given a 2X2 model (2 goods, 2 inputs), if the factor intensities (capital/labour ratio) of the two goods along the Pareto set are unequal, then we get a concave PPF. Can we get a convex PPF in some cases, for example with increasing returns to scale?